# Java - Should I encrypt/decrypt my socket communication?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, serversocket

I have a client/server application where each client has to send an ID and a password before they can actually start the communication.

Is that secure enough? Or should I also encrypt and decrypt the byte arrays?
Why is the Id and password way unsafe or safe? And would it be better to encrypt the sent data?

Comment: How are *we* to know what *your* requirements are? (Plain-text passwords over an insecure channel are generally frowned upon, however ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of transmition. If it is wi-fi then yes, if it is on a LAN network there's no need, if it is a safe connection.
But it wont hurt to put some security

If you just encrypt the data you are revealing some information about what it is been sent

Comment: It's over LAN. My question is just why everybody encrypts his socket communications. And why they don't just send passwords?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock Do *you* want *your* passwords stolen when you log into Gmail or Facebook? (They use HTTPS.)

Comment: Because you have to provide a secure software...and you can't always be sure about who will be connected, doing what

Comment: but if passwords aren't save encryption might not be save as well isn't it?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock That is why encryption is *done right*. It's not a trivial concept and preshared key approach to encrypt traffic is worthiness if an attacker knows the key. This is why approaches like SSH and SSL do not use a PSK.

Comment: And if I use encryption, should I send the key at the beginning of the communication or should I just define a key that'll never change but that also won't be transfered by the connection?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock No, you're doing it wrong again (*if you send the key in PT then the channel is a good as PT*). Stop. This is *not* something that can be discussed in comments. Instead, go read up on SSH and SSL and see *all the steps* that they do in order to establish a secure channel.

Comment: That depends on the encryption algorithm and on a strong protected key

Comment: Are there any good tutorials or articles?